# Can't connect to MariaDB server remotely using TCP

Tags: python, mysql, mariadb, raspbian

I know this kind of a question has been asked for a thousand times, but I still need to, because I assume that I'm doing everything right here and internet hasn't helped my out.

So I'm trying to remotely connect to my MySQL server (hosted by MariaDB 10.3.29 on Raspbian 10, Raspberry Pi 4). I've been trying to connect by using address 192.168.1.4 on my phone, another computer on another network, by using mysql server command line on a Windows PC and even on iOS using a QueryDB app.´

The exact error message I'm getting is:

```
ERROR 2003 (HY000): Can't connect to MySQL server on '192.168.1.4:3306' (10060)
```

Config file:

```
/etc/mysql/mariadb.conf.d/50-server.cnf
```

has this to be able to connect from any IP:

```
bind-address        = 0.0.0.0
```

as I think it should.
Also my ufw has mysql allowed, and port 3306 that I'm using, is allowed from anywhere.

I've done this:

```
GRANT ALL ON *.* TO 'user'@'%' IDENTIFIED BY 'my_pass';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

And to be sure I've checked that with

```
SELECT User, Host FROM mysql.user;
```

All seems to be OK. I still can't connect remotely. Of course I can connect from localhost, like another computer on my LAN.

I've also opened port 3306 on my ASUS router settings like this:

[ASUS router port forwarding](https://i.stack.imgur.com/EdA9Y.png)

Is that like it should be?
I really can't figure out anything causing this problem. According to information I've gathered, everything should be working. Thanks!

Comment: Please [edit] your question to describe how you are trying to connect– mysql client, python program, what?– and the exact error message you get.

Comment: Are you able to ping the mysql server ?, If yes then try doing `telnet 192.168.1.4 3306` and paste the result of ping & telnet here.

Comment: Trying these from a different network:

`Pinging 192.168.1.4 with 32 bytes of data:
Request timed out.
Reply from 10.64.201.250: Destination net unreachable.
Reply from 10.64.201.250: Destination net unreachable.
Reply from 10.64.201.250: Destination net unreachable.

Ping statistics for 192.168.1.4:
    Packets: Sent = 4, Received = 3, Lost = 1 (25% loss)`

`telnet 192.168.1.4 3306
Connecting To 192.168.1.4...Could not open connection to the host, on port 3306: Connect failed`

Comment: I'm not sure if being an idiot, but just to clarify, I want to reach my MySQL from anywhere in the world. And I think that the IP 192.168.1.4 in port 3306 is used by millions and yet millions of people. So do I need something else to be able to do so?

Isn't this a local but not a public IP? BTW I'm using phpmyadmin too.

Answer (score 0):

Ok, so after searching for three days I got this.

The problem wasn't with the MySQL but with the Apache. I needed to forward Apache's port 80 to connect to my Public IP address, not local of course.

So it works now!